# Which library building rich text editor for React native app?

Tags: javascript, react-native, text-editor, rich-text-editor

Anyone know library building text editor for react native app. I tried a lot of library but almost were deprecated.
[image]

Comment: Try this :- https://github.com/nikgraf/awesome-draft-js.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 libs that I've used and they aren't deprecated: 
https://github.com/wix/react-native-zss-rich-text-editor.
https://github.com/imnapo/react-native-cn-richtext-editor.

Comment: Hi, This library is not compatible with latest react-native version 61. Can you provider me any other link?